# Calling Dialog in AsyncTask throwing token error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an activity which when starts immediately calls for a server query. Below is its code.

Now suppose it started the `AsyncTask` and i get response in onSuccess. Before i get response if I quite the activity i-e press the back button.

Now The callback will still be called and showing dialog throws bad token exception. Unable to  add window token, Is your activity running. How can I disrupt this AsyncTask i-e If i press back button the execution of `onSuccess` stops execution?

```
ResponseCallback callback = new ResponseCallback() 
{
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String response) 
    {


            dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Chat.this).setMessage("BLABLA")
            .setTitle("Invite!")  
            .setCancelable(true)  
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,  
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {  
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
               {
                       dialog.cancel();
                       sendInvite();
               }  
            }) 
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {  
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
               {
                       dialog.cancel();
               }  
            })
            .show();
        }
        else 
        {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(String exception) 
    {}
};

new MyAsyncTask(queryString, callback);
```

Comment: Have you tried overriding `onBackPressed()` and calling `cancel()` on your `AsyncTask`?

Comment: yes i have, still did the same  if (asyncTask != null) 
   asyncTask.cancel(true);

Comment: You can wrap the .show() in a `try/catch`. This should prevent it from showing if the `Activity` is closed

Comment: that would do i think as a precaution

Comment: I'm not sure it wouldn't be all you need. I understand that most of the time you want to prevent exceptions but in this case I don't see what its hurting. If it can't attach the `Dialog` then you cancel and don't show it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just cancel the task because the `doBackground()` has already been performed.
You have to code yourself a check. For instance you can add a `activityDestroyed` boolean field to your `AsyncTask`, initialzed to `false`. Set it to `true` in the `onDestroy()` call of your activity. Then you can check the status before to show, or not, the dialog.

```
if (!activityDestroyed) {
    dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Chat.this).setMessage("BLABLA")
            .setTitle("Invite!")  
            .setCancelable(true)  
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,  
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {  
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
               {
                       dialog.cancel();
                       sendInvite();
               }  
            }) 
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {  
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
               {
                       dialog.cancel();
               }  
            })
            .show();
}
```

EDIT: You should be able to achieve that by a more proper way with `AsyncTask.cancel()` and `AsyncTask.isCancelled()`

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar issue a while back. A simple way to solve it is set a certain variable to true in `onBackPressed()`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    isFinishing = true;
    finish();
 }
```

Then in your `onSuccess` you just need to check if isFinishing is true.

EDIT: You might also use:

```
if(Chat.this.isFinishing())
```

in your `onSuccess`, but I'm not sure if this will return true as soon as you call `finish()`.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you go back, the task is still executing. I guess the correct way would be to abort the http connection with the server.

You may let your `AsyncTask` implement an interface, for example: `OnTaskCanceledListener` with a single method: `onTaskCanceled()`. 
The implementation of `onTaskCanceled()` should look like this (pseudocode):

```
@Override 
public void onTaskCanceled(){
   httpRequest.abort();
}
```

Now, when going back to previous activity, call `onTaskCanceled()` callback from the `AsyncTask`.
This way, you shouldn't pass throught `onSuccess()`